# Show that $3\cdot \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} + 210 = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2))!}$ for a specific n.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Show that:

$$3\cdot \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} + 210 = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2)!}$$ has the solution `n = 14` and also show that this is the only solution.

I don´t know where to start, the only reason I know that `n = 14` is a solution is that I used the trial.

Thanks!

/Alex

Comment: Note that $N!/(N-2)!=N\cdot (N-1)$. This simplifies your equation to a quadratic

Comment: Thanks! Your tips helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$3\cdot \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} + 210 = \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2)!}$$

Note that $$\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}=n(n-1)$$

and $$ \frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2)!}= 2n(2n-1) $$

Upon substitution and simplification, we get

$$n^2+n-210=0$$  Thus $n=14$ or $n=-15.$

The only positive solution is $n=14.$

Comment: Thanks for attention and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Write $\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}=n(n-1)$ and similarly $\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-2)!}=2n(2n-1)$ to get a quadratic equation in $n$.

Comment: Thanks! Your tips helped me a lot.